# SQL SYNTAX (node red)

Tags: mysql, node-red

in node red I send the data taken from a plc, through this function :

```
msg.topic = `insert into plc_valori_tag(numero_macchina, tag_macchina, valore_tag, data) values
(
'5',
'stato_macchina',
${msg.payload["numero_macchina"]},
${msg.payload["data_ora"]}
)`;
return msg;
```

data_ora is String.

But when I start the program I get the following error and I don't know how to solve it!

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':54:05)'

Thank you!

Comment: You need to escape those values. As this stands it has a [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a wrong use of backtics and quote

```
msg.topic = "insert into plc_valori_tag(numero_macchina, tag_macchina, valore_tag, data) values
('5','stato_macchina', ${msg.payload['numero_macchina']},${msg.payload['data_ora']})";
return msg;
```

Comment: hi, i've tried but didn't work , i've got the same error